# Clarification on Padding Process in BERT Model Construction

Tags: nlp, padding, bert-language-model, large-language-model

In my endeavor to construct a BERT model from the ground up for the purpose of gaining hands-on experience and a comprehensive understanding of the model, I have encountered a point of confusion regarding the padding process.

According to my interpretation of the `dataset.py` file in the [original repo](https://github.com/codertimo/BERT-pytorch/blob/master/bert_pytorch/dataset/dataset.py), the standard procedure involves concatenating two sentences and adding pad tokens at the end of the combined sequence, similar to typical padding practices in other tasks. Here's an example:

```
Sent_A= The cat is walking (Len is 4)
Sent_B= The dog is barking at the tree (Len is 7)

Maximum sequence length: 15

Sequence: The cat is walking The dog is barking at the tree [PAD] [PAD] [PAD] [PAD]
Segment: 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

However, in alternative implementations, I've observed padding aimed at equalizing the lengths of the two sentences, resulting in a structure like this:

```
Sent_A= The cat is walking (Len is 4)
Sent_B= The dog is barking at the tree (Len is 7)

Maximum sequence length: 15

Sequence: The cat is walking [PAD] [PAD] [PAD] The dog is barking at the tree [PAD]
Segment: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

This discrepancy has left me in a state of uncertainty—whether my understanding from the `dataset.py` file is accurate, or if the alternative implementations I've come across have a different rationale behind their padding approach. Could you kindly provide clarification on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation highlights a crucial aspect of data preprocessing for BERT models. For clarification, there are generally two approaches to this end:

1. Concatenation followed by padding at the end: This approach more aligned with the original BERT's pre-training objective, where the model is designed to understand the relationship between two sentences. By concatenating two sentences and then padding, the model gets a clear structure of two distinct segments, which is crucial for tasks like question-answering or next sentence prediction
2. Equalizing lengths with padding:  This approach, on the other hand, is less common in BERT contexts. It might be used in scenarios where individual sentence length needs to be normalized, possibly for models that focus on sentence-level tasks rather than inter-sentence relationships.

Comment: Great! In fact, I was not convinced by the idea of equal length of sentences from the beginning, but these implementations raised doubts in my mind. Thank you for the clarification.